# GSON/JSON - IF two attribute value match return Object

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm looking to search an array of JSON objects and if two attributes match the inputted values then I want that object to be returned. At the moment my code is returning if one attribute or the other attribute matches whereas I only want the object returned if both match.

My method:

```
 ArrayList<JsonObject> searchAttributes(String sensor, List<String> attributes, List<String> values) throws IOException {
   establishPastEventConnection(sensor);
   JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
   JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
   JsonArray rootArr = root.getAsJsonArray();
   JsonObject rootObj;
   ArrayList<JsonObject> results = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int x = 0; x < root.getAsJsonArray().size(); x++) {
     rootObj = rootArr.get(x).getAsJsonObject();
     for (String attribute : attributes) {
       for (String value : values) {
         if (rootObj.get(attribute).getAsString().equals(value)) {
               results.add(rootObj);
         }
       }
     }
   }
   return results;
 }
```

Method call:

```
nexaConnect.searchAttributes("13619978", Arrays.asList("timeStamp", "eventCode"), Arrays.asList("1.483384638619905E9", "1"))
```

Example JSON:

```
[
  {"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":0,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"136199","timeStamp":1.483384640123117E9,"uID":"136199_3_10"},
  {"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":0,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"136199","timeStamp":1.483379834470379E9,"uID":"136199_3_10"},
  {"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":0,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"136199","timeStamp":1.483384639621985E9,"uID":"136199_3_10"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add object only if both attributes are matched to given input values.
And finally returning the ArrayList object `results`.

```
for (int x = 0; x < root.getAsJsonArray().size(); x++) {
  rootObj = rootArr.get(x).getAsJsonObject();
   int i=0;
  for (String attribute : attributes) {

    for (String value : values) {
      if (rootObj.get(attribute).getAsString().equals(value)) {
           i++;
      }
    }
  }
   if(i==2){
      results.add(rootObj);
    }
}
return results;
```

Comment: It's returned an empty ArrayList for parameters that I know are correct. I changed `value1` to `values` was this correct?

Comment: yes that was a typo actually. Hey you changed `value1` to `values`, this may cause error make it `value`. `values` is a String list which gets compared to a string hence no object is added to your returned list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm migth be wrong, but I'm guessing you are looking for something like that :

```
public static ArrayList<JsonObject> searchAttributes(String sensor, Map<String, String> conditions)
        throws IOException {
    establishPastEventConnection(sensor);
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\Dev\\test.json")));
    JsonArray rootArr = root.getAsJsonArray();
    JsonObject rootObj;
    ArrayList<JsonObject> results = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
    for (int x = 0; x < root.getAsJsonArray().size(); x++) {
        rootObj = rootArr.get(x).getAsJsonObject();
        boolean match = true;

        for (Entry<String, String> condition : conditions.entrySet()) {
            String attribute = condition.getKey();
            String value = condition.getValue();

            if (rootObj.get(attribute) == null || !rootObj.get(attribute).getAsString().equals(value)) {
                match = false;
            }

        }

        if (match) {
            results.add(rootObj);
        }

    }
    return results;
}
```

You can call it that way :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Map<String, String> conditions = new HashMap<String, String>();

    conditions.put("timeStamp", "1.483384640123117E9");
    conditions.put("eventCode", "1");

    System.out.println(searchAttributes("", conditions));

}
```

Sorry if I misunderstood your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the attributes list and the values list have the same size:

```
mainLoop:
   for (int x = 0; x < root.getAsJsonArray().size(); x++) {
     rootObj = rootArr.get(x).getAsJsonObject();
     for (int i = 0; i < attributes.size(); ++i) {
        String attr = attributes.get(i);
        String value = values.get(i);
        if (!rootObj.get(attr).getAsString().equals(value)) {
           continue mainLoop;
        }
      }
      results.add(rootObj);
   }
```

Comment: Both lists have the same size, your code returned objects that were outside my listed values.

Comment: do you mean objects that had different attribute values that those in the list?